# WPF Controls: How to Reference Resources in Animations?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, styles, storyboard

I have written a control and successfully created a storyboard to cause an animation during triggered events. It changes the fill of an ellipse for a duration of time. Instead of writing a new `RadialGradientBrush` each time I need to change the fill, I provided two of them in the resources.

**EDIT**:
I have an `Ellipse` that is the main component to the control and is what is affected by the animation. It's implementation is simple and looks like this:

```
<Ellipse Name="myEllipse" Style="{StaticResource DimStyle}" />
```

When I add it to the storyboard (instead of referencing the brush as a resource), my animation works as intended. When I reference the brush as a resource I get this exception:

`"Cannot find resource named 'IlluminatedStyle'. Resource names are case sensitive."`

Inside of the storyboard, this is where it is currently referenced:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="Foo">
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames>
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.01" Value="{StaticResource IlluminatedStyle}" />
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.85" Value="{StaticResource DimStyle}" />
            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames>
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
     </Storyboard>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

The styles are closely identical and only the `GradientStop` color properties differ so I'll provide only one style for an example.

**The Style Referenced**

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="IlluminatedStyle" TargetType="Ellipse">
        <Setter Property="Fill">
            <Setter.Value>
                <RadialGradientBrush>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF215416" Offset="1"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FE38DA2E" Offset="0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FE81FF79" Offset="0.688"/>
                </RadialGradientBrush>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

So how do I correctly reference a style such as this in my `Storyboard`?

**Note**: The `Storyboard` and `Style` are both contained within the same `UserControl.Resources` tag but broken out for this example.

**EDIT**
I put the `Style` before the `Storyboard` in `UserControl.Resources` and now I get an exception stating:

```
  "This Freezable cannot be frozen.
   at System.Windows.Freezable.Freeze()
   at System.Windows.Freezable.GetCurrentValueAsFrozen()
   at System.Windows.Media.Animation.TimelineCollection.GetCurrentValueAsFrozenCore(Freezable source)
   at System.Windows.Freezable.CloneCoreCommon(Freezable sourceFreezable, Boolean useCurrentValue, Boolean cloneFrozenValues)
   at System.Windows.Media.Animation.Timeline.GetCurrentValueAsFrozenCore(Freezable sourceFreezable)
   at System.Windows.Freezable.GetCurrentValueAsFrozen()
   at System.Windows.Media.Animation.Clock..ctor(Timeline timeline)
   at System.Windows.Media.Animation.TimelineGroup.AllocateClock()
   at System.Windows.Media.Animation.Clock.AllocateClock(Timeline timeline, Boolean hasControllableRoot)"
```

Comment: They are both in the same UserControl.Resources, but in what order?  The resources being referenced (by a StaticResource) must come before the one referencing it.

Comment: The Style is after it in the resources. That matters in WPF? I'm a bit surprised because I can write a class after another in a CS file yet still reference the bottom class in the top class and compile correctly.

Comment: Order matters with StaticResources, not with DynamicResources.

Comment: @Jon, I added the stacktrace as well as the KeyTime property values in the DiscreteObjectKeyFrames. @Wonko, is it ideal to make my resources Dynamic in this scenario?

Comment: Run the app inside the debugger and when the exception is thrown see which `Freezable` exactly is the parameter of `GetCurrentValueAsFrozenCore` (3rd on the call stack). You 're the one with the debugger here, make use of it. :-)

Comment: @jlafay: there is a performance trade-off with Dynamic vs. Static resources.  Generally, Dynamic resources are used for things that will change (i.e. it's one way of implementing label binding for apps that allow a language change).  Here, you are always using the same resource, so Static is probably the better way.  You are better off figuring out the issue with the Freezable, which @Jon has started you down the path on.

Comment: When the exception throws, the $exception.Source is "WindowsBase" but I'm sure that doesn't help you. I tried a breakpoint where the calling method invokes Begin() on the Storyboard in hope that I could step into the call but it throws when Begin() is invoked.

Comment: You need to break into the debugger as the exception is thrown to inspect the call stack. To do that, see what the exception type is and use this technique to have the debugger break automatically: http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/VSBreakOnException.aspx

Comment: It already breaks in the debugger, I'm not receiving any additional information. The FAQ isn't helpful in my case because I still don't know how to find what you're asking for. As I stated it breaks when the control's codebehind method is invoked and that method invokes Begin() on the storyboard. Where do I find the data you're asking for?

Comment: Since I'm getting no where I also added the line of code that's the prime component to the control. I can't step through the animation XAML since it doesn't allow me to add breakpoints. Honestly, what are you looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing that I am new to WPF and XAML I made the mistake of making my resources a style and did not realize that I could have simply made the brushes a resource and avoid styles altogether.

I kept the reference to the `DiscreteObjectKeyFrame`s' values as static to the new brush resources. I changed the Ellipse to this:

```
<Ellipse Name="myEllipse" Fill="{StaticResource DimBrush" />
```

The style property was removed and I assigned the brush to the fill property directly. In the `ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames` tag I added `Fill` as the `Storyboard.TargetProperty` since I was no longer using a style to dress up the fill. The `DiscreteObjectKeyFrame`s now look like this:

```
<DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.01" Value="{StaticResource IlluminatedBrush}" />
<DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.85" Value="{StaticResource DimBrush}" />
```

My resources are much simpler without being wrapped in a style and IMO, more elegant. Also the brushes are defined before the animation in my final solution.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <RadialGradientBrush x:Key="DimBrush" >
        <GradientStop Color="#FF21471A" Offset="1"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#FF33802F" Offset="0"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#FF35932F" Offset="0.688"/>
    </RadialGradientBrush>
    <RadialGradientBrush x:Key="IlluminatedBrush">
        <GradientStop Color="#FF215416" Offset="1"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#FE38DA2E" Offset="0"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#FE81FF79" Offset="0.688"/>
    </RadialGradientBrush>
    <!-- Storyboard code follows... -->
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Everything is now working as intended. The best assumption I can make is that styles are not freezable since they were the components that I removed and I no longer receive exceptions regarding a freezable that cannot be frozen.

Answer (score 3):

There are three reasons why a `Freezable` cannot be frozen:

- It has animated or data bound properties.
- It has properties that are set by a dynamic resource.
- It contains Freezable sub-objects that cannot be frozen.

So, first find out which `Freezable` is causing trouble and then check the above.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I'm new to WPF and appreciate the guidance.

Comment: Considering it's a storyboard animation thats throwing that exception I suppose that makes sense but doesn't make sense considering it will run when I don't reference the KeyFrame values as Styles. Maybe I should give up on the code reuse and leave this one be. I don't know where to tackle the issue.

Comment: I came up with a solution, but wasn't able to debug how you were requesting. Thanks anyways.